# file not showing up in render derbyjs

Tags: derbyjs

I have a new file:

message.html

Restarting node doesn't seem to get it to render. Pointing derby to render a different file works, just not "message".... I assume the filesystem or something is having an issue.

For the record, it isn't the html file as I copied and pasted other files that do work....

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I didn't import the html file...

```
<import: src='./message'>
```

It was in a higher file so I forgot about it....